# Jquery mobile 1.4.0 and phonegap 3.3.0 not working correctly

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a SPA ios application using phonegap and having some issue with Jquery mobile the lastest version (1.4.0). The pages do not fit to the screen of the iphone but they appear one after another and I can scroll down to view all my pages ! (possibly data-role = "page" is not working correctly. Can anyone shed a light on this. Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Home</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
        <!--<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/soapclient-1.2.js"></script> <!-- for soap v1.1 use js/soapclient.js -->
        <script src="js/EmailComposer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.imageLens.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/touchable.js"></script>
        <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="js/date.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/timetoport.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/imageslogic.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/loadingScript.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/LoginController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/kmlMap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/tools.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moduleScripts/dataService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                InitializeLoginScreen();
                CheckDisclaimer();
            });

            $("#discpage1").live("pageshow",function() {
                $("#agree").click(function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('disclaimerAccepted', true);
                    tools.GoForward("#loginPage");
                });
                $("#disagree").click(function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('disclaimerAccepted', false);
                    navigator.notification.alert('To ccontinue you must accept the Disclaimer', null, '', 'OK');
                });
            });

            $(document).delegate(".scroll-disabled", "scrollstart", false);
            </script>
    </head>

    <body id="boddy">

        <!-- LOGIN PAGE -->
        <div data-role="page" id="loginPage" class="scroll-disabled">
            <div data-role="header" class="header" >
                <div id="LoginHeader" class="headerText">Login</div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/shiplogo.png" id="logobspt">
                        <label id="ship2Go">Ships to go</label>
                </div>

                <div id="loginContainer">
                    <div>
                        <label for="uid" id="uidLabel">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" value="test" name="uid" id="uid" placeholder="Enter username" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="loaderdiv" style="height:50px;width:100px;padding:5px;margin-left:87px;margin-top:-12px;display:none;">
                        <img src="images/loading3.gif" id="loadingimg" style="margin-left:30px;">
                            <div id="loadingMsg">
                                <center >Please wait...</center>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="pwd" id="pwdLabel">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" value="test" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="Button" id="loginButton">Login</div>
                <div data-role="footer">
                    <div id="envLabel"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- DISCLAIMER PAGE -->

        <div data-role="page" id="discpage1" class="scroll-disabled">
            <!--<div id="dleftpanel"></div>
            <div id="drightpanel"></div>-->
            <div id="dcontent">
                <div id="bplogo"></div>
                <div id="shiplogo"></div>
                <div id="discHeading">Disclaimer</div>
                <div id="agree" class="Button discButton">I have read and I agree</div>
                <div id="disagree" class="Button discButton">Disagree</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These are the relevant values in my config.xml file:
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens to me (as - I admit - it does from time to time), it is ALWAYS that the CSS file for jQuery Mobile is missing, linked to the wrong path, or I have a typo (used a "dot" instead of a "dash" more often than not).

Any chance that could be it?

A quick way to check is to open up the file you pasted in above in Chrome (or whatever) and look at the debug console for any messages throwing a fit about the CSS file.